# Python - comparing two dicts values for contains and showing matches

Tags: python

I can see lots of similar questions but imo not having much luck finding an answer.

I have two dictionaries with values I want to match against but with different keys. ive attempted a match query but its returning empty. I think its because of the miss matching key names maybe? or not iterating the k,v pairs? But im not sure what to do here

```
interface_list = [
        {'ifIndex': 19, 'Caption': 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0 *** Uplink ***', 'ifType': 131, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
        {'ifIndex': 19, 'Caption': 'GigabitEthernet0/0/1', 'ifType': 131, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
        {'ifIndex': 19, 'Caption': 'GigabitEthernet0/0/2', 'ifType': 131, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
        {'ifIndex': 19, 'Caption': 'Tunnel100', 'ifType': 131, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
        {'ifIndex': 20, 'Caption': 'Vlan5', 'ifType': 53, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
        {'ifIndex': 21, 'Caption': 'Vlan10', 'ifType': 53, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
        {'ifIndex': 22, 'Caption': 'Vlan15', 'ifType': 53, 'ifSubType': 0, 'InterfaceID': 0, 'Manageable': True, 'ifSpeed': 0.0, 'ifAdminStatus': 0, 'ifOperStatus': 4},
]

wanted_interfaces = [{'resource': 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0'}, {'resource': 'Vlan5'}]

>>> matches = [i for str(i) in wanted_interfaces if i in interface_list]
>>> matches
[]
```

it should hopefully return the record containing 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0 *** Uplink ***' as a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a comprehensive scan (assuming you want to check every value in every dict in both lists), you would have to do something like:

```
matches = [
    v for d1 in interface_list for v in d1.values() 
    if any(isinstance(v, str) and vw in v for d2 in wanted_interfaces for vw in d2.values())
]
# ['GigabitEthernet0/0/0 *** Uplink ***']
```

Comment: thank you this works as desired, I would never figured that out

Comment: is it possible to return the full dictionary for the matches?

Comment: Yeah, just start the comprehension with `[(d1['ifIndex'], v) for d1 ...` instead of `[v for d1 ...`

Comment: sorry I changed it to the full dictonary is that one possible?